# Error while using Google Place Picker in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm following the google place picker method for getting the place while `click` on a button. I have added frameworks and follow same pattern as it is described by google using `objective-c` language. But when I run the app I got an error , its very difficult to find out where the actual location of it is, I'm confused how I can get rid from this. The error is shown in a screen shot down.

[image]

Comment: you are using old version swift somewhere in your project.

Comment: How to get it where it is to be changed? @Yatendra

Comment: search in your project where you are using swift.

Comment: no i'm not using swift anywhere its only objective-c. @Yatendra

Comment: have you using "GooglePlaces-2.4" downloaded from here

Comment: yes i have copied it in my project. @Yatendra

Comment: try this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431282/how-can-i-update-swift-from-3-1-to-3-2-but-not-to-4-0

Comment: I'm not getting it why i should change the version of swift which i'm not using it in my project. @Yatendra

Comment: When i change the version of swift to swift 3 it shows this error #import "GooglePlacesDemos/Samples/Autocomplete/AutocompleteWithTextFieldController.h" this header file is not found . @Yatendra

Comment: because of it's giving swift version errors,I think your project have swift file unfortunately.

Comment: How to get rid now? is there any solution? @Yatendra