# Is xcode 8.3.3 running swift 3.2

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4, xcode9

With Xcode 9 and swift 4 out, I keep seeing that you have to migrate from swift 3.2. Currently I am running Xcode 8.3.3 which shows my swift compile language as swift 3.

Some places have said swift 3.2 is the name given in Xcode 9 and it's what is referred to as swift 3 in Xcode 8.3.3. Is this correct? Am I already running swift 3.2 in Xcode 8.3.3 but it's just labeled as swift 3? If not, how do I get to swift 3.2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update swift from 3.1 to 3.2, but not to 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431282/how-can-i-update-swift-from-3-1-to-3-2-but-not-to-4-0)

Comment: Similar but not duplicate, I want to clarify if Xcode 8.3.3 is running swift 3.1 or 3.2 and labeled it as swift 3 under the 'swift language version'.

Comment: Xcode 8.3.3 -> 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42)
ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode

Comment: Swift 3.2 is a stopgap solution to continue using Swift 3 code under Xcode 9 without fully converting projects to Swift 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30790542/4076101, you can run `xcrun swift -version` to know which Swift version is your Xcode using.